# Powershell Scheduled Task only runs part of a script 'At Startup'. Script runs fine if run manually

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I got the main block of code from [this webpage](https://www.pdq.com/blog/modifying-the-registry-users-powershell/) about modifying hkey_users registry settings

```
$PatternSID = 'S-1-5-21-\d+-\d+\-\d+\-\d+$'
$ProfileList = gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*' |
Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -match $PatternSID} |
 Select @{name="SID";expression={$_.PSChildName}},
  @{name="UserHive";expression={"$($_.ProfileImagePath)\ntuser.dat"}},
  @{name="Username";expression={$_.ProfileImagePath -replace '^(.*[\\\/])', ''}}
$LoadedHives = gci Registry::HKEY_USERS | ? {$_.PSChildname -match $PatternSID} | Select @{name="SID";expression={$_.PSChildName}}
$UnloadedHives = Compare-Object $ProfileList.SID $LoadedHives.SID | Select @{name="SID";expression={$_.InputObject}}, UserHive, Username
Foreach ($item in $ProfileList) {
 if ($item.SID -in $UnloadedHives.SID) { reg load HKU\$($Item.SID) $($Item.UserHive) | Out-Null }
 ###################
 function ru( $path, $name, $value ) {
  $path = "registry::HKEY_USERS\$($Item.SID)\" + $path
  if( -Not( Test-Path $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) ) { New-Item -Path $path }
  New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $name -Value $value -Force
 }
 ru "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" "NoAutoTrayNotify" 1
 ru "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" "DisableNotificationCenter" 1
 ###################
If ($item.SID -in $UnloadedHives.SID) {
 [gc]::Collect()
 reg unload HKU\$($Item.SID) | Out-Null
 }
}
```

If I run this in powershell it runs just fine, but when I run it using a scheduled task with the following settings, this part of the code doesn't run. I've tried it with additional code to modify hkey_local_machine registry settings and that part of the script runs, just the above portion doesn't run when set as a scheduled task.

```
$name = "ps-startup"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $name -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -Action $action -Settings $settings
```